# python import error: partially initialized module 'aiohttp' has no attribute

Tags: python, discord.py

I have gotten a error on one of my python scripts and I have no idea what it is and google has been no help. what is this error and how could I fix it?

code snippet:

```
import discord
import os
import asyncio
from discord.ext import commands
from discord.ext.commands import Bot
from discord.utils import get
import requests, random, replit
import json

intents = discord.Intents(members=True, messages = True, guilds=True,)
BOT_PREFIX = ("!")
client = commands.Bot(command_prefix=BOT_PREFIX, intents = intents)
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix=BOT_PREFIX, intents = intents)
```

error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Parents/Desktop/Documents/python/json.py", line 3, in <module>
    import discord
  File "C:\Users\Parents\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\discord\__init__.py", line 25, in <module>
    from .client import Client
  File "C:\Users\Parents\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 33, in <module>
    import aiohttp
  File "C:\Users\Parents\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\aiohttp\__init__.py", line 6, in <module>
    from .client import (
  File "C:\Users\Parents\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\aiohttp\client.py", line 6, in <module>
    import json
  File "C:/Users/Parents/Desktop/Documents/python\json.py", line 10, in <module>
    from discord.ext import commands
  File "C:\Users\Parents\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\__init__.py", line 13, in <module>
    from .bot import Bot, AutoShardedBot, when_mentioned, when_mentioned_or
  File "C:\Users\Parents\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\bot.py", line 37, in <module>
    from .core import GroupMixin
  File "C:\Users\Parents\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 36, in <module>
    from .cooldowns import Cooldown, BucketType, CooldownMapping, MaxConcurrency
  File "C:\Users\Parents\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\cooldowns.py", line 32, in <module>
    from ...abc import PrivateChannel
  File "C:\Users\Parents\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\discord\abc.py", line 40, in <module>
    from .voice_client import VoiceClient, VoiceProtocol
  File "C:\Users\Parents\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\discord\voice_client.py", line 50, in <module>
    from .gateway import *
  File "C:\Users\Parents\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\discord\gateway.py", line 214, in <module>
    class DiscordClientWebSocketResponse(aiohttp.ClientWebSocketResponse):
AttributeError: partially initialized module 'aiohttp' has no attribute 'ClientWebSocketResponse' (most likely due to a circular import)
```

Comment: You've named your own script `json.py`, which is being imported instead of the actual module of that name.  Rename it, and get rid of any `json.pyc` or similar file in the same location.

Comment: yes that was the problem thank you!

Answer (score 3):

I had the exact issue.The issue was I was importing the `aiohttp` module inside a file that named as the same that is `aiohttp.py`. This was causing the circular import issue when I changed the file name it got resolved.
Other things to try are:

1. Check that you're using the correct version of aiohttp. If you've installed multiple versions of aiohttp, you might be importing the wrong version.
2. Try importing `aiohttp` in a different way, such as using an absolute import or importing specific functions or classes from the module. For example, instead of `import aiohttp`, you could try `from aiohttp import ClientSession`.